# Websocket connection closes without opening on Shotgun server

Tags: ruby, websocket, sinatra, shotgun

I have a Sinatra app that uses Websockets.
My app works when I run it with `ruby app.rb`, but doesn't when I'm trying to run it with `shotgun app.rb`.

This is in my **sending_out.erb**:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
connection = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname);
connection.onopen = function(){
    $("#msgs").append('Connection opened'+"<br>")
};
connection.onmessage = function(e){
    $("#msgs").append(e.data+"<br>");
};
connection.onclose = function() {
    $("#msgs").append('Connection closes from view'+"<br>");
};
$("form").submit(function(){
    connection.send( $("input").val() );
});
});
</script>
```

And this is in my **app.rb**:

```
require 'sinatra-websocket'
set :sockets, []
get '/sending_out' do
request.websocket do |connection|
  connection.onopen do
    connection.send("Hello World!")
    settings.sockets << connection

    connection.send("opened")
    connection.send("went")

  end
  connection.onmessage do |msg|
    EM.next_tick { settings.sockets.each{|s| s.send(msg) } }
  end

  connection.onclose do
    warn("websocket closed")
    settings.sockets.delete(ws)
  end
end
end
```

It must show

```
Connection opened
Hello World!
opened
went
```

when I go to the page. But it only shows

```
Connection closes from view
```

with **Shotgun**.

And in the console it says **WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9393/sending_out' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500**.

Is there an issue running Websockets with Shotgun?

Answer (score 2):

The main feature of Shotgun is that it automatically reloads your whole code every request and I think that could be also the problem you are facing.

Shotgun should be used just for development.

For production purposes you have plenty of other options available:

- [Puma](http://puma.io/)
- [Rainbows](http://rainbows.bogomips.org/)
- [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/)
- [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/)
- others

Comparison of ruby servers can be found on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-comparison-of-rack-web-servers-for-ruby-web-applications

Comment: I don't know if it will work because I already don't have this code, but in case someone was facing my problem and it got resolved by this answer, please tell me this so I can accept it.